# Registration e-mail body translate doesn’t work

Tags: emails, 9

Admin page: **/admin/config/people/accounts**
Tab: **Welcome (no approval required)**

The translation of the subject of the e-mail works perfectly.
However, the translation of the body of the email does not work. It only loads the default translation defined in the po file, regardless of what we write in the admin interface.

How to fix this?

Comment: How are you testing this?  How did you do the translation? 
 AFAIK, Drupal never loads translations directly from a PO file.  Default translations are **imported** from a PO file when first downloaded, but they are not loaded dynamically.  Obviously what you are experiencing is abnormal behavior, so there is probably an issue with your site configuration.

Comment: Thx.
Where should I look for the wrong setting in the configuration?
And why does the email subject work correctly?
Why is only the body of the email like this?

Comment: I can't say without more information.  Normally, Drupal handles this properly.  So you should write down the exact steps that you took that resulted in this issue.

Comment: The page where the error occurred is before handover.
I will try to find out the cause of the error by debugging.
It would be a great help if I knew in which parts of the Core system the translation of this field takes place.
Maybe someone knows this?